# Are there any proven set of recommendations for JBoss clustering

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

Are there any proven set of recommendations for JBoss clustering like

1. Recommended number of minimum physical machines  for JBoss cluster?
2. How do we conclude on RAM requirement for Spring+Hibernate based Apps to be run on JBoss server instance?
3. What is possible Minimum number of CPUs to be available for each Application server instance?
4. Is it better to have more physical boxes with less number of Application server instances per box or less number of physical boxes with more number of Application server instances?
5. A recommended way of weight-based load balancing if available on JBoss?
6. What is the right proxy plug-in for load balancing and right algorithm to do that?

Appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Seeing words like "ideal" and "better way" make me wonder if you can define and quantify either one.  It's doubtful for your special case; it's even more difficult for a general case.

Your choices are restricted to the techniques that JBOSS clustering makes available to you (e.g. round robin, least busy, etc.)  The hard work of choosing and tuning to create an optimum solution is up to you.  The answer is likely to depend on the details of your situation.  No one knows those, except perhaps you.

P.S. - That's what I'd call a run-on sentence.  I'd refactor that question into several if I were you.  Add some punctuation.

Comment: Hi duffmo! Thanks for keeping me informed. I agree with you. I tried changing the query with the help of guidelines.